# Add reference to using MSXML2

Tags: c#, c, visual-studio, reference, msxml

I would like to add reference to

```
using MSXML2;
```

So that I can use

```
XMLHTTP xmlhttp = (XMLHTTP)new XMLHTTPClass();
```

I tried adding the ref to

> C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll

but at my ref i keep getting the error

> This project cannot be viewed in the object browser because it is unavailable or not yet built

Im using .NET Framework 3.5

Any recommended solutions for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add the reference to `C:\Windows\System32\msxml3.dll`? I tested it, and it works fine in .Net Framework 4.7.2. Maybe you can check it.

Comment: Im using .Net Framework 3.5 cause the project is an old one. Yes i already added the ref to the msxml3.dll